# Подсчет количества одинаковых символов в строке и вставка этого значения в строку

Tags: bash

Например, имеется строка Aaaaaaaaabbbbbb. На выходе должно получится Aaaaaaaaa9bbbbbb6

В баше новичок. Нужно ли здесь пытаться как-то по-символьно в цикле перебирать строку, сравнивать с предыдущим значением, увеличивать счетчик, если значения равны и перезаписывать в новую строку. Если да, то как это сделать в bash? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: явно требуется уточнение: вам нужна реализация именно языковыми средствами оболочки, или, что проще, но более ресурсоёмко, средствами программ, входящих в операционную систему *gnu* (*coreutils+(sed|awk)*)?

Comment: ну и вообще насчёт учебных заданий вы же в курсе? а алгоритм элементарный — как и для любого языка программирования: перебираем символы по одному, если очередной символ не совпадает с предыдущим, выводим значение счётчика и обнуляем его, иначе увеличиваем значение счётчика на единицу.

Comment: В Perl это можно сделать очень легко.

Comment: @alexander barakin что попроще

Comment: Чтобы было что-то попроще, надо сначала что-нибудь сложное написать. Что у вас получилось?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew пока только посимвольный перебор строки

Comment: Т.е. всё-таки вам в Bash нужно. Ясно.

Comment: `y=$(echo "$x" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'); j=0; k=$(echo "$y" | cut -c1); for i in $(seq $(echo "$y" | wc -c)); do l=$(echo "$y" | cut -c$i); if [ "$k" = "$l" ]; then j=$((j+1)); else echo -n "$j"; j=1; k=$l; fi; m=$(echo "$x" | cut -c$i); echo -n $m; done; echo`. Оптимизации и разбор сделаете сами. И что самое важное, это работает не только в `bash`. Если хочется совсем портируемого варианта, то тогда вместо `echo -n` надо использовать `printf '%s'`.